# Wildfly 13 deployed service not responding after some time

Tags: web, server, wildfly, redhat, wildfly-13

Api is deployed on a wildfly 13 red hat server it received a heavy load. after some time
wildfly access log not writing any request have received but we can see that api is consumed by multiple devices. but if we telnet the ip and port it is working. We can see the api is working because internal logs are being written. When this happens we have to always restart the wildfly.
reloading is not working at that moment. Another thing we observe is that normally request count exceed 1 million (around 1.2 and 1.5 million requests) all the http sessions are invalidated we cannot  see any memory leaks even from the api level(no gradual increase in cache, ram usage).

In to this also when start the server
datasource statistic as below
[image: Start of wildfly server]

After few days of running but still working
[image: Few days of running]

Max used connection not displaying but running
[image: Max used not showing]

[image: Jboss Cli at this time]

Even from above state the requests are processing

Finally The Requests are not processing but applications are running
[image: Requests are not processing admin console]

[image: Requests are not processing Jboss Cli]

Below are the my Datasource configuration at standalone xml

```html
<datasource jndi-name="java:/EAPG_CON" pool-name="EAPG_CON" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/******?autoReconnect=true&amp;useSSL=false</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>20</min-pool-size>
                        <initial-pool-size>20</initial-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>200</max-pool-size>
                        <flush-strategy>AllGracefully</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>******</user-name>
                        <password>******</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <use-fast-fail>true</use-fast-fail>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.mysql.MySQLExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                    <timeout>
                        <idle-timeout-minutes>2</idle-timeout-minutes>
                    </timeout>
                </datasource>
```

Below is my default-server settings

```html
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:6.0" default-server="default-server" default-virtual-host="default-host" default-servlet-container="default" default-security-domain="other" statistics-enabled="true">
            <buffer-cache name="default"/>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" tcp-keep-alive="true" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="50000000" always-set-keep-alive="false" record-request-start-time="true" no-request-timeout="10000" request-parse-timeout="2000" redirect-socket="https" enable-http2="true"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <location name="/download" handler="download-dir"/>
                    <http-invoker security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default" default-session-timeout="60">
                <jsp-config/>
                <websockets/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content"/>
                <file name="download-dir" path="*************" directory-listing="true" follow-symlink="true"/>
            </handlers>
        </subsystem>
```

another thing I notice here is if I set tcp-keep-alive to undefined then this happens quickly

below is the spec of PC we use
[image: PC Spec]
Any Idea why this is happening Please advice

Comment: Does Anyone face such a problem. advice How to solve this

Comment: do you have solved it?

Comment: Still not sure I removed using Wildfly JNDI and added HikariCP for db communication still snder test

Comment: With the introduction of HikariCP Issue seems to fixed. Wildfly running smoothly for 3 months now without any issues.